# JS Files empty After Running > php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Tags: magento2

I have noticed that requireJs and other files are empty after running 
`> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

It will create the file but nothing is ever written to the file. 
Per another recommendation I have set the following from symlink to Copy
`<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
</item>`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was. It looks like a number of my static files are empty. Particularly in the lib folder. Not sure how it happened but restoring the files from source control seems to have worked.

This was happening on my dev machine.